# some questions before applying for postdoc

Tags: postdocs

I appreciate your guidance on the following questions:

1. Should I inform my adviser before applying for each an every postdoc position?
2. Should I send my research statement to my Ph.D adviser before sending it for postdoc applications?

Comment: Your PhD advisor? (Why should they be informed before you apply for your next position?) What research statement? (Why should your PhD advisor be sent such a statement?)

Comment: @user2768 A PhD advisor could offer useful feedback on the research statement. Many postdoc positions want one. The adviser could also tell if the institute and the people there have good reputations in the field.

Comment: @TommiBrander That might be a reason, but is it the OP's reason? It's difficult to offer advise with so little information. (In my first question, I meant to ask: in question 1, does "advisor" mean "PhD advisor" or some other advisor? That's unclear as stated.)

Comment: I mean by advisor, PhD advisor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, you should be communicative with your PhD advisor about your applications. This is so that they can do their job and advise you about the process. Their input will be invaluable to you. In particular, you will probably want your PhD advisor to write recommendation letters for you.

You should tell your advisor in advance that you are planning to apply. (Although it is usually not necessary to specify exactly where.) And, once you have applied, you should tell them where so that they are on the look out for a letter request.

However, if you have a problematic relationship with your advisor, then that's a big problem that you will need to navigate. If this is the case, then your question should make this clear.